# Sending multipart/form-data with image files from Actionscript to PHP

Tags: php, image, actionscript-3, post, multipartform-data

There are quite a few questions on SO that deal with sending image `ByteArray`s from Actionscript to PHP, however, none seems to fit me specific problem.

I want to send ONE post request from my flash application that contains some text fiels as well as several images.

The sending of one image I got to work by sending one image's `ByteArray` directly as the `URLRequest`'s `.data`, but when I want to add more images, this approach does not work any more. I figures out how to construct and post a `multipart/form-data` with text fields and also found how to mark up the image data so they will be available in PHP's `$_FILES` array.

BUT with this method, I can't get the image `ByteArray` data to send properly.

With this code that constructs the request in actionscript:

```
var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest(uri);
request.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
request.contentType = "multipart/form-data; boundary=fooboundbar";

var _data:String ="";
_data += "--fooboundbar\n";
_data += "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"userId\"\n\n";

_data += _userId + "\n";
_data += "--fooboundbar\n";
_data += "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"title\"\n\n";

_data += _title + "\n";
_data += "--fooboundbar\n";
_data += "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"screenshot\"; filename=\"screenshot.jpg\"\n";
_data += "Content-Type: image/jpeg\n";
_data += "Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary\n\n";

_data += _screenshotByteArray.toString() + "\n";
_data += "--fooboundbar\n";
_data += "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"design\"; filename=\"design.jpg\"\n";
_data += "Content-Type: image/jpeg\n";
_data += "Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary\n\n";

_data += _designByteArray.toString() + "\n";
_data += "--fooboundbar\n";
_data += "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"test\"\n\n";

_data += "test\n";
_data += "--fooboundbar--";

request.data = _data;

trace(_data);
```

I get a proper trace from actionscript with the boundaries in place. The problem is, that the `_screenshotByteArray` and `_designByteArray` data contain line breaks which mess up the whole post. The request basically ends after the first line of the `_screenshotByteArray` and does not include the second image nor the last "test" form-data field.

The var_dump from my PHP script confirms this:

```
array(2) {
  ["userId"]=>
  string(1) "0"
  ["title"]=>
  string(9) "undefined"
}

array(1) {
  ["screenshot"]=>
  array(5) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(14) "screenshot.jpg"
    ["type"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["tmp_name"]=>
    string(14) "/tmp/phpXZxIqg"
    ["error"]=>
    int(0)
    ["size"]=>
    int(8)
  }
}
```

Also note the ["size"]=>int(8); that is basically the first 8 bits, i.e. the first line of the ByteArray of the image.

I tried different `Content-Type`s for the images, also tried a different `Content-Transfer-Encoding`, but that does not seem to take effect.

I also considered if I would just encode the `ByteArray`s with base64 and decode them on the PHP side, but that didn't work with the `$_FILES` array, nor could I get it to work by sending the base64 encoded image as a normal text field and then store it to a file, somehow the content-type got messed up with that.

SO, with all the questions about sending one encoded image from Actionscript to PHP, **what is the correct way of sending multipe images and form data from Actionscript to PHP?**

Comment: You've forgotten to put the `--fooboundbar` separator between on the "design" file, meaning its data is actually part of the "screenshot".

Comment: @MarcB Oh you are right! But that was a mere coping error. I double checked and in my actual code it is present; Also that does not explain why all of the screenshot file that arrives on the PHP is 8 bits. I'll update the code sample in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This class is working for me for this case: https://github.com/jonasmonnier/Multipart.as